# Expected value of a sum of die rolls

Tags: probability, expected-value

You roll a standard six-sided die, then roll n more six-sided die, where n was the first roll.
What is the expected value of the sum of all the die you rolled?

I did some calculations, but I'm not sure.
Let expected value of the sum of all the die rolls be E[X], then
$$E[X] = \frac{3.5}{6}+2\frac{3.5}{6}+3\frac{3.5}{6}+4\frac{3.5}{6}+5\frac{3.5}{6}+6\frac{3.5}{6}$$
because the expected value of each single die is 3.5. Is it correct?

Comment: E.V. by definition is a sum of products of values and probabilities. For n dices you have up to 6n different sums (in fact it's less: 6n - n + 1). Try to start from value = n (the minimum one, all 1s), calculate its probability (obviously it's 1/6n), then go to 2, 3 etc. You'll be able to build a formula for P(x(n)) - a probability of an event than n rolls sum up to x and then it's just a matter of calculating the sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the outcome of the first six-sided die. Then you want to find
$$
\mathbb{E}[N + \sum_{i = 1}^N X_i]
$$
where $X_i$ is the outcome of the $i$-th six-sided die. The trick is to condition on the value of $N$. Assuming that $N$ can be any value between 1,..,6 we have:
$$
\mathbb{E}[N + \sum_{i = 1}^N X_i] = \sum_{j = 1}^6 \mathbb{E}[N + \sum_{i = 1}^N X_i | N = j]\mathbb{P}(N = j) = \sum_{j = 1}^6 (j + \mathbb{E}[\sum_{i = 1}^j X_i])\mathbb{P}(N = j),
$$
Then you can fill in the known $\mathbb{P}(X = j)$ and use that
$$
\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i = 1}^j X_i] = \sum_{i = 1}^j \mathbb{E}[X_i]
$$
when $i,j$ are known.

Comment: Aah, I understand now. I think I have done the mistake of not including the expected value of the first throw of the die. Thanks, I'll remember to condition property in problems of expected value and answer systematically.